# Convert data set to binary data

Tags: r

I have a data set I want to convert to binary data (1 or 2).  The probability of obtaining 1 differs for each value in the original data set.  I have written code below that does this, but my code seems far too complex.  Is there a quick and easy way to do this in `base R`?  I am sure there is, but my mind is drawing a blank.

My code converts the original data set `my.data` into the binary data set `my.result`.  The `for-loop` creates probabilities to use in converting `my.data` into `my.result` by comparing `my.probs` and `random.draw`.

```
set.seed(1234)

# observed field data
my.data <- read.table(text = '
   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   4   3   7  11   0   0   0   0   0
    1   5   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   1   1   3   5   7   9  11   0   0
    0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   3  11  11  11   0   0   0   0   0
    0   4   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   5   1   9  11   5   0   0   0   0
', header = TRUE)

# values of field data
my.bins <- seq(1, 11, 2)

# vector of probabilities corresponding to each value of field data
prob.by.bin <- c(0.99, 0.80, 0.6, 0.40, 0.20, 0.01)

# create a matrix of probabilities for each value of observed data
my.probs <- matrix(NA, ncol = (ncol(my.data) - 2), nrow = nrow(my.data))

for(i in 1:length(my.bins)){
     my.probs[my.data[,3:ncol(my.data)] == my.bins[i]] = prob.by.bin[i]
}

my.probs
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [2,] 0.99   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [4,] 0.80 0.40 0.01   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [5,] 0.60   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [6,] 0.99 0.80 0.60  0.4  0.2 0.01   NA   NA
# [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [8,] 0.01 0.01 0.01   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [9,] 0.40   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[10,] 0.99 0.20 0.01  0.6   NA   NA   NA   NA

# Create a matrix to convert field data to values of 1 or 2 based on probabilities in my.probs
my.result <- matrix(0, ncol = (ncol(my.data) - 2), nrow = nrow(my.data))

random.draw <- matrix(runif((ncol(my.data) - 2) * nrow(my.data), 0, 1), ncol = (ncol(my.data) - 2), nrow = nrow(my.data))
random.draw
#             [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]
# [1,] 0.113703411 0.6935913 0.31661245 0.4560915 0.5533336 0.07377988 0.86483383 0.12148019
# [2,] 0.622299405 0.5449748 0.30269337 0.2651867 0.6464061 0.30968660 0.04185728 0.89283638
# [3,] 0.609274733 0.2827336 0.15904600 0.3046722 0.3118243 0.71727174 0.31718216 0.01462726
# [4,] 0.623379442 0.9234335 0.03999592 0.5073069 0.6218192 0.50454591 0.01374994 0.78312110
# [5,] 0.860915384 0.2923158 0.21879954 0.1810962 0.3297702 0.15299896 0.23902573 0.08996133
# [6,] 0.640310605 0.8372956 0.81059855 0.7596706 0.5019975 0.50393349 0.70649462 0.51918998
# [7,] 0.009495756 0.2862233 0.52569755 0.2012480 0.6770945 0.49396092 0.30809476 0.38426669
# [8,] 0.232550506 0.2668208 0.91465817 0.2588098 0.4849912 0.75120020 0.50854757 0.07005250
# [9,] 0.666083758 0.1867228 0.83134505 0.9921504 0.2439288 0.17464982 0.05164662 0.32064442
#[10,] 0.514251141 0.2322259 0.04577026 0.8073523 0.7654598 0.84839241 0.56456984 0.66849540

my.result[!is.na(my.probs) & random.draw <= my.probs] = 1
my.result[!is.na(my.probs) & random.draw >  my.probs] = 2
my.result[ is.na(my.probs)                          ] = 0
my.result
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    1    2    2    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [6,]    1    2    2    2    2    2    0    0
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [8,]    2    2    2    0    0    0    0    0
# [9,]    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[10,]    1    2    2    2    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: @akrun I suspect a complete rewrite would be most efficient.  My code seems far too complex and cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

The first part with `for` loop can be modified with a named `vector` to match and modify

```
my.probs[] <- setNames(prob.by.bin, my.bins)[as.character(unlist(my.data[-(1:2)]))]
```

---

Regarding the second part, it is just converting the logical to numeric index, so adding `1` will coerce the logical to indexing from 1 (as `TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 2).  The `NA` values can be later replaced with 0

```
my.result <- ((random.draw > my.probs) + 1)
my.result[is.na(my.result)] <- 0
```

Comment: Very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get `my.probs`:

```
my.probs <- as.matrix(my.data[, -c(1, 2)])
my.probs <- matrix(prob.by.bin[match(my.probs, my.bins)], 10, 8)
my.probs
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#  [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#  [2,] 0.99   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#  [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#  [4,] 0.80 0.40 0.01   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#  [5,] 0.60   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#  [6,] 0.99 0.80 0.60  0.4  0.2 0.01   NA   NA
#  [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#  [8,] 0.01 0.01 0.01   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
#  [9,] 0.40   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [10,] 0.99 0.20 0.01  0.6   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works.  I have not tried timing it versus @akrun's answer.  Here I convert the non-zero elements of `my.data` into a `vector`.  Then I create a corresponding `vector` of probabilities instead of a `matrix` of probabilities.  Then I use `rbinom` to create a `vector` of successes and failures instead of creating a `matrix` of random draws.  Once I have the `vector` of successes and failures I assign them to the appropriate `elements` of `my.results` using `which`.

I was thinking this approach might be faster because I largely restrict myself to just the non-zero `elements` of `my.data`.  However, I imagine this code might be so sloppy that it still turns out to be slower than @akrun's solution.

In one step I do make use of a modified version of @dcarlson's answer.

```
set.seed(1234)

# Convert observed field data into binary data (1 or 2).
# The probability of converting to 1 differs for each value of the field data 

# observed field data
my.data <- read.table(text = '
   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9 X10
    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    1   4   3   7  11   0   0   0   0   0
    1   5   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   1   1   3   5   7   9  11   0   0
    0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   3  11  11  11   0   0   0   0   0
    0   4   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   5   1   9  11   5   0   0   0   0
', header = TRUE)

# values of field data
my.bins <- seq(1, 11, 2)

# vector of probabilities to obtain '1' corresponding to each value of field data
prob.by.bin <- c(0.99, 0.80, 0.6, 0.40, 0.20, 0.01)

# convert non-zero elements of my.data into a vector
input.data.vector <- t(as.matrix(my.data[, 3:ncol(my.data)])) [t(as.matrix(my.data[, 3:ncol(my.data)]) > 0)]
input.data.vector
#[1]  1  3  7 11  5  1  3  5  7  9 11 11 11 11  7  1  9 11  5

# probability of obtaining '1' for each element of input.data.vector
probs.vector <- prob.by.bin[match(input.data.vector, my.bins)]
probs.vector
#[1] 0.99 0.80 0.40 0.01 0.60 0.99 0.80 0.60 0.40 0.20 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.40 0.99 0.20 0.01 0.60

# obtain output value of '1' or '2' for each element of input.data.vector
# where '1' is success and '2' is failure
replacement.values <- sapply(1:length(input.data.vector), function(x) {

                           rbinom(1, 1, prob = probs.vector[x]) })
replacement.values
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1

replacement.values[replacement.values == 0] = 2
replacement.values
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1

# assign replacement values to a matrix corresponding to my.data
x.row <- which(my.data[, 3:ncol(my.data)] > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]
y.col <- which(my.data[, 3:ncol(my.data)] > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2] + 2
i <- cbind(x.row, y.col)

my.results <- my.data
my.results[i] <- replacement.values
my.results
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#1   1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#2   1  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#3   1  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#4   1  4  1  1  2  0  0  0  0   0
#5   1  5  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#6   0  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  0   0
#7   0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#8   0  3  2  2  2  0  0  0  0   0
#9   0  4  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
#10  0  5  1  2  2  2  0  0  0   0
```